# Transfer database from PostgreSQL 12 to PostgreSQL 9.2.24

Tags: postgresql

I need to transfer db from PostgreSQL 12 to PostgreSQL 9.2.24. I try make backup my db from PostgreSQL 12 and restore on PostgreSQL 9.2.24 but I can't do it because have an error like this:

```
LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.schemas_headers_types_id_se...
                                 ^


LINE 2:     ADD CONSTRAINT user_id PRIMARY KEY (id) INCLUDE (id);
                                                    ^
Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.users
```

...

I can't update db version from PostgreSQL 9.2.24 to PostgreSQL 12 because my hosting provider doesn't allow me to do it. How i can't truly transfer my db from  PostgreSQL 12 to PostgreSQL 9.2.24?

Comment: How are you doing your dump? Postgresql have different options on `pg_dump` formats. I believa that you can try the `custom` format. As follows: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 1):

You would have to edit the dump to remove the `INCLUDE (id)` (which is a pretty useless use of the INCLUDE feature anyway, to include the same column twice).  But who knows how many following on errors you will find?

> my hosting provider doesn't allow me to do it

Seems like the real solution then is find a different hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

[pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) says...

> Also, it is not guaranteed that pg_dump's output can be loaded into a server of an older major version — not even if the dump was taken from a server of that version. Loading a dump file into an older server may require manual editing of the dump file to remove syntax not understood by the older server. Use of the --quote-all-identifiers option is recommended in cross-version cases, as it can prevent problems arising from varying reserved-word lists in different PostgreSQL versions.

`include` is a feature which simply does not exist in Postgres 9.2. These and other features will have to be replaced with alternates, if possible.

[9.2.24 reached its end-of-life in November 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Release_history). It's possible you can use this fact to get your provider to upgrade. If not, consider whether you want to use a hosting provider which refuses to update software which is no longer supported.